# problem ssh to my ansible-controller

Tags: boot, networking, permissions, ssh, openssh

am having problem with connecting with my ubuntu using Mobaxterm. when putting my password it brings out this reply: ansible-controller-Node@192.168.56.109's password:
Access denied

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.